# php fwrite only works on localhost not server?

Tags: php, localhost

I'm a new PHP developer. I'm trying to write a flat file on server, and I have the following code.

```
<?php 
$myfile= "file1.txt";
if(isset($_POST['ta'])){
    $newData = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($_POST['ta']));
    $handle = fopen($myfile, "w");
    fwrite($handle, $newData);
    fclose($handle);
}

if(file_exists($myfile)){
    $myData=file_get_contents($myfile);
}
?>

<form action="file.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="ta" cols="64" rows="10"><?php echo $myData; ?></textarea>
    <br/> <br />
    <input name="myBtn" type="submit" />
</form>
<br/> 
<br/> 

<?php echo $myData; ?>
```

What I don't understand is that how come the above program works perfectly on localhost but is doing nothing on the actual server?

Comment: What user is the webserver running as? Does that user have write permissions to that directory/file on the server?

Comment: this is a server that my school gives out to the students, so yea. i think i do? how can i check?

Comment: Do you have ssh access to your web directory? If so you can go there and look at what the permissions are on that file and/or the directory  you're trying to write to. Failing that, add some error handling to your code and see at which point exactly it's failing and why. I'd almost guarantee though that the web user doesn't have write permission.

Comment: so seems like that i hv the write permission as owner

Comment: oh god! i love you ultranaut! i just edited the write permission to public, and it worked!!! cant find a better way to express my love to you now!!

Comment: Well, that's one way to "fix" it, but it's dangerous, and I'd seriously look for a different solution.

Comment: oh yea...thats another good point. how do i actually assign the access ability to a different user??

Comment: i dont like to bother ppl tho...can u please recommend a couple websites that teach PHP? i'll go to study there. =)

Comment: It's not really a php issue per se, you should google info on file permissions and ownership, and get an understanding of at least the basics of how a web server operates. There's tons of info out there.

Comment: i see. thank you for the help! i'll definitely google on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check to see if the file is writeable by the user the web server is running as, which is probably something like `www`, `apache` or something, and is distinct from your user --`wjones17` or whatever for example. If your permissions look something like

```
-rw-r--r--   1 wjones17  group     17 Nov 17 20:02 index.php
```

then your user has permission to make changes to that file, but nobody else does, including the web server, and consequently your php script which is running as `www`, `apache` or whatever.

In terms of how to fix that, your options may be limited in a shared environment, but granting  full priveleges to all users is definitely a bad idea; though it might seem to "fix" the problem, you're just opening yourself up to much larger problems. You might ask yourself if there's another way to accomplish what you want, such as using a database. It all depends on your situation and what you're trying to do though.